# hover element below other element possibly hovered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with my css.
i have some element generated by javascript and when i hover them i display another element but i don't know why, the new element displayed is below the others generated element...

this is my css about this problem:

```
.hiddenTextjob
    {
        display:none;
        background-color:#000;
        color:#FFF;
        width:170px;
        z-index:2!important;
        height:55px;
    }

    .ghost_for:hover > .hiddenTextjob
    {
        display: block;
        background-color:#000;
        color:#FFF;
        width:170px;
        margin-top:-55px;
        z-index:1!important;
    }
    .ghost_for
    {
        border: 0;
        position:absolute;
        background-color:blue;
        z-index:1!important;
    }
```

.hiddenTextjob is below ghost_for but he must be above...
Thanks by advance

[EDIT] here a jsfiddle to illustrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/95jtx2oL/

when you hover a blue element sometine the black hover is above sometime he is below that make me mad...

Comment: Can you share the HTML structure also?

Comment: Sorry it's too difficult the structure is generated by php and this is table on table on table and am using jquery ui draggable and droppable to resize or move these elements.
the ghost for element are placed over a table (i make a job schduler)

Comment: it is too difficult to suggest solution just by looking at CSS classes, you need to post at least relevant HTML

Comment: @Fangster Just inspect in the browser and copy-paste the rendered part :) CSS is hard to debug without proper HTML structure reference. We can give you some hit and try code but it will just increase our work. Do consider ^^

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar i try but it's to difficult... Am sorry my code is too big and diffcult...

Comment: @Himanshu Bansal not work in jsfiddle to big i have 390 <td> by <tr> and I color the td according to the ghost above by positioning the ghost_for over all the colored tds

Comment: @Fangster you can remove the rest and just use 2 td or tr..for reference. It doesn't have to be full code. The above CSS will work for 2 rows or columns too :P..

Comment: @Himanshu Bansal thats good i succeeded:
https://jsfiddle.net/95jtx2oL/

Comment: @Fangster answered ^^ Let me know if this works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ghost_for:hover {
    z-index: 2!important;
}
```

The above code is enough to fix the issue ^^ [jdfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh5a61ky/)

The issue was because of the stacking of HTML. The lower elements will be higher if they are on the same index. So if you can raise the z-index of the hovered element, it's child element will be higher as well.

Comment: sure no problem!! Happy to help ^^.. please mark as accepted :) so that others can find it helpful too

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit strange that you set `z-index` to `1` here.

```
.ghost_for:hover > .hiddenTextjob
{
    display: block;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    width:170px;
    margin-top:-55px;
    z-index:1!important;
}
```

The initial value of `2` seems correct. Try to remove `z-index` from the above code or set it to `2`.

Comment: Can the z-index of a child-element even be higher than that of the parent-element?

Comment: Sure, it can. The purpose of the property is to change the initial order of the elements on z-axis.

Comment: Not work... no change if i put 2 at z-index or no Z-index

Comment: Try to put a bigger value like 100 )

Comment: @Sergey same result here you can see:
https://jsfiddle.net/95jtx2oL/

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your HTML but try this if it works for you:

```
.hiddenTextjob {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 170px;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  height: 55px;
}

.ghost_for:hover > .hiddenTextjob {
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: -55px;
}
.ghost_for {
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: With z-index: -1; the ghost_for element disappear...